# Can I optimize this canvas draw call that takes up 30% of my memory profiling?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

My game has many Laser objects. mx & my represent velocity. I use the following code to draw a line from behind the Laser 2 pixels to ahead of the Laser in the direction it's going 2 pixels.

Removing the first line of the function adjusted the % of the Profiling by ~1% but I don't like the way it looks. I think I could optimize the drawing by sorting by Linewidth but that doesn't appear to get me much.

How else could I optimize this?

```
Laser.prototype.draw = function(client, context) {
    context.lineWidth = Laser.lineWidth;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.x - this.mx * 2, this.y - this.my * 2);
    context.lineTo(this.x + this.mx * 2, this.y + this.my * 2);
    context.strokeStyle = this.teamColor;
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Do you [draw to an off-screen canvas](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/)?

Comment: @KenY-N I do not, in my initial testing drawing to an offscreen canvas slowed the game dramatically because the positions were updating each frame. I will look at your link and try that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiplying things by two, why not add them?
E.g.

```
context.moveTo(this.x - this.mx - this.mx, this.y - this.my - this.my);
context.lineTo(this.x + this.mx + this.mx, this.y + this.my - this.my);
```

Testing shows that addition is an order of magnitude faster on an imac over multiplication

https://jsfiddle.net/1c85r2pq/

Answer (score 0):

Dont use moveTo or lineTo as they do not use the hardware to render and are very slow. Also your code is drawing the line twice

```
ctx.beginPath(); // starts a new path 
ctx.moveTo(x,y);  // sets the start point of a line
ctx.lineTo(xx,yy); // add a line from x,y to xx,yy

// Not needed
ctx.closePath(); // This is not like beginPath
                 // it is like lineTo and tells the context
                 // to add a line from the last point xx,yy
                 // back to the last moveTo which is x,y
```

This would half the already slow render time.

A quick way to draw lines using bitmaps.

First at the start create an image to hold the bitmap used to draw the line

```
function createLineSprite(col,width){
    var lineSprite = document.createElement("canvas");
    var lineSprite.width = 2;
    var lineSprite.height = width;
    lineSprite.ctx = lineSprite.getContext("2d");
    lineSprite.ctx.fillStyle = col;
    lineSprite.ctx.fillRect(0,0,2,width);
    return lineSprite;
}

 var line = createLineSprite("red",4); // create a 4 pixel wide red line sprite
```

Or you can use an image that you load.

To draw a line you just need to create a transform that points in the direction of the line, and draw that sprite the length of the line.

```
// draw a line with sprite from x,y,xx,yy
var drawLineSprite = function(sprite,x,y,xx,yy){
   var nx = xx-x; // get the vector between the points
   var ny = yy-y; 
   if(nx === 0 && ny === 0){ // nothing to draw
        return;
   }
   var d = Math.hypot(nx,ny); // get the distance. Note IE does not have hypot Edge does
   // normalise the vector
   nx /= d;
   ny /= d;
   ctx.setTransform(nx,ny,-ny,nx,x,y); // create the transform with x axis
                                       // along the line and origin at line start x,y
   ctx.drawImage(sprite, 0, 0, sprite.width, sprite.height, 0, -sprite.height / 2, d, sprite.height);
}
```

To draw the line

```
drawSpriteLine(line,0,0,100,100);
```

When you are done drawing all the lines you can get the default transform back with

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

The sprite can be anything, this allows for very detailed lines and great for game lasers and the like.

If you have many different colours to draw then create one sprite (image) that has many colour on it, then in the line draw function simply draw only the part of the sprite that has the colour you want. You can stretch  out a single pixel to any size so you can get many colours on a small bitmap.

Comment: Wrt "many different colors to draw" - having multiple bitmaps of single lines would hurt only RAM, not performance, right?

Comment: Why did you say it's drawing the line twice? MoveTo doesn't draw, right? I'm just seeing the stroke() as drawing once

Comment: @quantumpotato ctx.closePath creates the second line by closing the path with a line. And no you have many lines from one bit map see last paragraph

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that's what closePath did.

Comment: drawLine is not a function, searching for the definition

Comment: @quantumpotato Sorry my mistake should be `ctx.drawImage` had lines on the mind. Will fix it now..

Comment: First, using a transformed "line-sprite" is a seriously cool way of drawing a line!!! :-D But native moveTo & lineTo appear to be [faster](https://jsfiddle.net/kzzjj1ga/)

Comment: @MarkE head to head Path2d (or moveTo, lineTo, lineTo, ... n) V sprites lines, the pathed lines will win, but if you need lines drawn in a game where objects are layered and line calls are not in order, line widths/ styles vary, or line widths are big ( > 4-8 pixels), this is faster. If you then need gradients this is much faster. It is also reliant on the GPU, low end GPUs will not compete as well as high end GPUs. Also this method is not good at joining lines. A well written game will have rendering alternatives for dynamic load balancing as there is so much variation across devices.

Comment: @Blindman67. Good to know...makes sense that drawImage outperforms paths except for simple situations. :-)